# Mongodb querying using $date field

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, mongosh

I am newbie in mongodb and trying to query a document based on date and it is not working.

```
db.orders.insertOne({ _id: 6, item: "chocaltes" , qty: 1, price: 10, order_date: {"$date": 1322006400000}})
```

Details:

```
mongodb version: 6.0.12
```

Find Query:

```
db.orders.find({order_date: ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z" )})
```

[image]

it should return the document.

Comment: you sure you insert that document correctly? use `new Date(1322006400000)` instead of `{"$date": 1322006400000}`

Comment: I am not sure if It is correct or wrong but above are the statements I ran.
I am referencing from an exercise I am working on...so I was hoping that what they provided is correct, I am not sure if it is an older version of Mongo, it is 3.4 which they used.

Comment: after insert, run `db.orders.find()` and check if document inserted correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
db.orders.insertOne({ 
  _id: 6, 
  item: "chocaltes", 
  order_date: { "$date": 1322006400000 } 
})
```

This inserts a document into the collection. And, any of the following two queries return that document.

```
db.orders.find()
db.orders.find({ "order_date.$date": 1322006400000 });

[
  {
    _id: 6,
    item: 'chocaltes',
    order_date: { '$date': 1322006400000 }
  }
]
```

Note the `order_date` field. It is of type `object`, with one embedded field `$date`. As of MongoDB version 5, you can have field names starting with `$` sign (see [Field Names with Periods (.) and Dollar Signs ($)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/)).

So, the value for the embedded field `order_date.$date` is a of data type `double` with a value `1322006400000`.

> Find Query: `db.orders.find({order_date: ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z" )})`

This will not return the document.

To return a document using the date `ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z")` you will need a query like this:

```
db.orders.find({ 
  $expr: { 
    $eq: [ 
      { $toDate: { $getField: { field: { $literal: "$date" }, input: "$order_date" } } }, 
      ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z") 
    ] 
  }
})
```

Note the usage of `$getField` operator. This is for using the field names with `$` sign. The `$toDate` converts the number `1322006400000` to a date type. The `$toDate` is an aggregation operator. To use an aggreation operator in a `find` query  you need to use the `$expr` operator.

Comment: While this answer is right with respect to the format of the `insertOne` given in the question, I doubt that OP actually intends to have a document shaped like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the following way.

> gte:2022-02-07T00:00:00.000Z
> lte:2022-02-07T23:59:59:999Z

The reason for this is that:

> To expand a bit on the answer, the dates are stored as full date-time value. Think of it as ISODate("2022-02-07T00:00:00.000Z") is storing February 7th 2022 at midnight. Comparing ISODate("2022-02-07T00:00:00.000Z") and ISODate("2022-02-07T01:00:00.000Z") will not show them as equal since the full “datetime” is being compared.

This answer has been quoted from:
[Query date range of the same day](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-date-range-of-the-same-day/146171/2)

Thank You
WeDoTheBest4You